# CSS3 opacity effect

Tags: html, css

I've found a piece of CSS code that works pretty well on my website but am having troubles having the effect work exactly to specification.

What I'm trying to do: I'd like the images at default to have an opacity of 1.0, but when you scroll over any of the images then the images will go to an opacity of 0.3. This currently works, and you can view the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/raybullard/C8NMs/

Below is the HTML and CSS:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="columns" class="columns_3">
    <div class="figure">
        <a href="http://www.burton.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ruU04I6.jpg"></a>
       </div>
    <div class="figure">
        <a href="http://www.burton.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ruU04I6.jpg"></a>
       </div>
    <div class="figure">
        <a href="http://www.burton.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ruU04I6.jpg"></a>
       </div>
    <div class="figure">
        <a href="http://www.burton.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ruU04I6.jpg"></a>
       </div>
    <div class="figure">
        <a href="http://www.burton.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ruU04I6.jpg"></a>
       </div>

#wrap{
width:240px;
}
.columns_3 .figure{
width:70px;
margin-right:0px;
}
.columns_3 .figure:nth-child(3){
margin-right: 0;
}

#columns .figure:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transform:scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);

}
#columns:hover .figure:not(:hover) {
opacity: 0.4;
}
div#columns .figure {
display: inline-block;
background: #FEFEFE;
border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
margin: 3px 3px 3px 0px;
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
column-break-inside: avoid;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
-o-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

div#columns .figure img {
width: 60px;
height:50px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

The problem is that the entire #columns div is called out, and since I have only 5 icons if you scroll over where the sixth icon 'should be' the entire div changes opacity.

What I'd like to do is to have the non-active icons change opacity to 0.3 at the .figure level (rather than #columns level) when a user scrolls over an icon if possible.

Any help/suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: It works fine for me. Except if I don't understand your question.

Comment: Yes, should have updated the HTML base. Check the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/raybullard/C8NMs/3/. At this point I have 5 icons and if you scroll over where the 6th one 'should' be then the entire div goes to opacity of .3. I'd like to not have this possibility at this point and for the opacity to happen at the .figure level. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't make sense... what's this about where the 6th one "should be". It's there, I can see it. It's not clear what the effect your after is.

Comment: Sorry this is unclear. So if you go to this link http://jsfiddle.net/raybullard/C8NMs/3/ you'll see that the second row down, third icon over is not there. But, if you hover over this area the effect still happens. What I'd like to do is make it so the opacity effect only happens when you scroll over an icon, and not the entire #columns div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add property value of **display: inline** to **#columns** block of CSS code and you're good to go.

**Solution:** Adding property value of **display: inline** to **#columns** Makes it technically present only in the areas where it contains something.

```css
#columns {
  display: inline;
 /* This block of CSS solves your problem */
}
#wrap {
  width: 240px;
}
.columns_3 .figure {
  width: 70px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.columns_3 .figure:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#columns .figure:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
#columns:hover .figure:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
div#columns .figure {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FEFEFE;
  border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 0px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
div#columns .figure img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="columns" class="columns_3">
    <div class="figure">
      <a href="http://www.burton.com">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ruU04I6.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="figure">
      <a href="http://www.burton.com">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ruU04I6.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="figure">
      <a href="http://www.burton.com">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ruU04I6.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="figure">
      <a href="http://www.burton.com">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ruU04I6.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="figure">
      <a href="http://www.burton.com">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ruU04I6.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if you're open to jquery, but here's a solution with jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/C8NMs/6/

This solution works for all elements with class .figure, no matter where you place them on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.figure').on('mouseover', function() {
        var element = $(this);
        $('.figure').not(element).css('opacity', 0.4);
    })
    $('.figure').on('mouseout', function() {
        $('.figure').css('opacity', 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: This will work great and not affect any of my layout - thanks so much! If I could vote this solution up I would!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the columns div extend to the size to its child, and is being hovered.

If you don't need more positioning in the rest of the layout, you can cut it

```
.columns_3 {
    height: 0px;
}
```

and so avoid it being hovered

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C8NMs/7/)

Comment: This technically works - but I indeed do have positioning in the rest of the layout so this may not actually work.